# UITextField should accept only positive integers and give alert message for rest

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

What Code I need to write to make my UITextField accept only positive integers(Whole numbers) other than setting keyboard Type to numbers only. And it should alert user when they input characters/fractions/Negative numbers/Special Characters. Kindly, Let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the UITextFieldDelegate method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {}
```

In it you can check the textField's text property and convert it to an NSNumber using the NSNumberFormatter class method numberFromString: and see if the intValue is positive.

Comment: Well , I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

What I do, is to **create avalidate function**, which I call every time the UITextFieldDelegate method - [textFieldDidEndEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting?language=objc) is fired.

The other option is to validate all fields at the end when you save information.

For integers I found that the following works well (Using [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsscanner)):

```
- (bool)validateFields {
    if (textField.text.length > 0) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: textField.text.length.text];
        double d;
        BOOL success = [scanner scanDouble:&d];
        if (!success) {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(d < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to call delegate method as well?? and yes thanks for the help. I will try this one too and let you know.

Comment: This will depend in your approach... if you want to find out with text changed

Comment: if you want to find out with text changed, you can use: textFieldShouldReturn...
If you want to find out when the textfield resigns as first responder, you can use: textFieldDidEndEditing ...
However if you want to do it as part of a validation process just before you save, you do not need to use a delegate method. In this case you can use a button action to test it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better way, but you can use the UITextFieldDelegate - [textFieldDidEndEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting?language=objc) and prove the entered text yourself and in case somebody entered something 'wrong' show an AlertController

Comment: Well, I will try this and let you know, how it worked